# How to keep mac awake while updating

Tags: sleep-wake, software-update, system-settings, big-sur

I am upgrading from mojave to big sur and need to know how to keep my mac awake during this time. the terminal command caffeinate did not work, after some time the screen display went blank as usual. Is there a way to prevent the mac from going to sleep? Also, If i went to System Preferences > Energy Saver > Battery and put "Turn Display Off After:" to never, will the update be able to override that when it needs to restart the computer after the update file has installed?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to achieve. Do you want to install the update without a restart?

Comment: Letting the screen go dim won’t affect things. Also, the download is incremental and accumulative, so it’s not clear what you’re struggling with - wrong [syntax or terminal issues](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/364623/5472) or just you’re worried about interruption?

Answer (score 3):

The easy way at the command line is to call software update.

```
softwareupdate --all --install --restart
```

The command prevents sleep, checks for all updates and then installs them. If the install requires a reboot, that happens immediately as well once the install is done.

Comment: need sudo  and -R for restart from what i can see, but thank you for this

Answer (score -1):

There is a free app called Caffeine which prevents sleep on the mac, google search for it.

Comment: How does it improve on caffineate which either the app you mention calls or it uses that same API.