# Slack prevents Mac from sleeping

Tags: mac, sleep-wake, slack

Slack is preventing my Mac from sleeping. I can see this information in the Activity Monitor.
How can I disable it? I want my mac to sleep even when Slack is open.

Comment: Update 2021: same issue, the only way to allow my mac to go to sleep while plugged-in is to quit the Slack app... :(

Comment: At some point after restarting my machine, slack stopped preventing my mac from sleeping. I have no idea what was changed.

Comment: I think it keeps it awake after you do a Huddle. I had to restart the app after a hudd to go back to not keeping it awake.

Comment: Slack has recently been made aware of this issue.

Comment: @NoelYap is there a ticket or something like that?

Answer (score 4):

It's the "Slack Helper" service preventing your mac from sleeping.

If you open the Activity Monitor and terminate the service, it will go to sleep.

Comment: It might apply only when you use an HDMI monitor as your sound output: that is what I see by experimenting with switching to built in speakers.

Comment: For me just terminating Slack did the trick: Slack then no longer prevented sleep. It might be related to having used the huddle feature. There was also continuous use of around 6% CPU by the coreaudiod, which also was stopped by restarting Slack.